# Linker error: error adding symbols: bad value with GNU ARM toolchain

Tags: gcc, arm, static-libraries, ld, elf

I am trying to build an application for ARM with the [ARM GNU Toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/arm-gnu-toolchain-downloads) (version 11.3 for now). To do so, I have a main program that I need to link to a static library `foo` that transitively depends on another static library `bar`.

Compiling the libraries and main program to ELF object files succeeds. But whenever I try to link any combination of the program and libraries together by running e.g. `arm-none-eabi-gcc foo.o bar.o -o foobar.o` I get fatal errors of the form:

```
c:/arm_toolchain_11/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: foo.o: in function `no symbol':
(.text.fooSome_Function+0x0): multiple definition of `no symbol'; foo.o:(.text.fooSome_OtherFunction+0x0): first defined here

...

c:/arm_toolchain_11/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: foo.o: .symtab local symbol at index 8830 (>= sh_info of 8046)
c:/arm_toolchain_11/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: foo.o: error adding symbols: bad value
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can't find anywhere what these kinds of linker errors generally tend to mean.

Running `file` on the object files returns the following:

```
# file foo.o
foo.o: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), not stripped

# file bar.o
bar.o: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

You can see the results match.

Running `readelf -sW` on the files gives output ending like:

```
readelf: Warning: local symbol 8830 found at index >= .symtab's sh_info value of 8046
```

(with only the numbers differing). To me this indicates that GCC has somehow generated an invalid ELF file, but this seems very unlikely.

Finally, I am building this in MSYS2 on Windows.

Unfortunately, I cannot provide source code.

Is there anyone who could shed more light on this?

Thank you in advance!

Best regards,
Joshua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the complex custom build system I was using to build the libraries was actually using Keil and not the GNU ARM Toolchain. If I compile and link everything with Keil's armclang I can avoid the problems and link everything together just fine. I think the problem is probably with Keil not implementing the exact same ARM C ABI as the GNU ARM toolchain (with the latter probably implementing it incorrectly seeing as ARM itself owns Keil). This would somewhat explain GCC/ld for ARM complaining about symbols in wrong places or having weird values.

Answer (score 0):

This command: `arm-none-eabi-gcc foo.o bar.o -o foobar.o` is probably wrong.

You are asking GCC to link a *complete* executable program, and name that program `foobar.o`.

Either you intended to combine `foo.o` and `bar.o` into a single *object* file `foobar.o`, in which case you are linking two relocatable object files and building another relocatable object file, and must use the `-r` flag.

Or you really are trying to link a complete executable program, in which case you should *not* name the resulting executable `foobar.o` to avoid confusing everyone.

Showing what your *actual* link command is likely to help here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You raise an excellent point that I didn't know about. The use of -o can indeed be inappropriate.